# calling ffmpeg.c function inside native.cpp in android cmake

Tags: ffmpeg, cmake, android-ndk

i generated and attached `libavcodec.so,libavdevice.so,libavfilter.so,libavformat.so,libavutil.so,libswresample.so,libswscale.so` using `cmakelists.txt` file

```
add_library( # Sets the name of the library.
        native-lib

        # Sets the library as a shared library.
        SHARED

        # Provides a relative path to your source file(s).
        native-lib.cpp )

#Add an example of so library.
# avdevice
add_library(avdevice
        SHARED
        IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(avdevice
        PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION
        ${ARM_DIR}/${ANDROID_ABI}/lib/libavdevice.so)
.
.
.
etc
```

In `native-lib.cpp` file i can now edit videos by calling this functions `avformat_open_input()`. As i could see its very difficult and also very few examples available in ffmpeg for c functions api(native code). I now decide to call ffmpeg `main()` and pass commands as argument.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4
```

I could see many do by this method only. I dont know the exact difference between these two methods but i think i can customise more if i do it with c functions api(native code).

Now i have only library's shared object like `libavcodec.so` . How do i attach `ffmpeg.c` file and i think it needs `config.h` file that too i think i should build for each environment(arm64-v8a,armeabi-v7a). Since i have only `native.cpp` c++ file how do i attach `ffmpeg.c,config.h` files with it? So that i can run commands by

```
run(new String[]{
            "ffmpeg", "-h"
        });
   -------------------------------------
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_uk_co_halfninja_videokit_Videokit_run(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jobjectArray args)
{
    int i = 0;
    int argc = 0;
    char **argv = NULL;
    jstring *strr = NULL;

    main(argc, argv);
```

I could see this git repo. They first generated .so files and attached the `ffmpeg.c` which they took from `ffmpeg/fftools` directory i think, by using `Android.mk` file.
github.com/halfninja/android-ffmpeg-x264/blob/master/Project/jni/videokit/ffmpeg.c

Since im having cmake i have to do in different method i think. Im confused and dont understand how it works. Anyone know can help! Thanks

Comment: so you want to link ffmpeg as a shared library and then call into its `main(...)` function?

Comment: yes i want to link ffmpeg as `ffmpeg.so` and then call into its main(...) function